# Android- How to make video using set of images from sd card?

Tags: android

I want to create a video using images from a sdcard through my application in android.

Comment: please see my answer...

Comment: Here's my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839777/878126

Answer (score 1):

Use Frame animation

An animation defined in XML that shows a sequence of images in order (like a film).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot=["true" | "false"] >
    <item
        android:drawable="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource_name"
        android:duration="integer" />
</animation-list>
```

[refer this:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Comment: I understood what you have explained above but how to retrieve images from sd card and convert into video files.Actually i am looking for converting jpeg into mpeg or 3gp format.

Comment: Programmatic frame by frame animation examle - AnimationDrawable http://androidforums.com/application-development/11620-programmatic-frame-frame-animation-examle-animationdrawable.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
 path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Testing/";

    commandEditText.setText(
                "-loop 1 -i "+path+"images_001.jpg " +
                        "-loop 1 -i "+path+"images_002.jpg " +
                        "-loop 1 -i "+path+"images_003.jpg " +
                        "-loop 1 -i "+path+"images_004.jpg " +
                        "-loop 1 -i "+path+"images_005.jpg " +
                        "-filter_complex " +
                        "[0:v]setsar=sar=40/33,trim=duration=1,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v0];" +
                        "[1:v]setsar=sar=40/33,trim=duration=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v1];" +
                        "[2:v]setsar=sar=40/33,trim=duration=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v2];" +
                        "[3:v]setsar=sar=40/33,trim=duration=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v3];" +
                        "[4:v]setsar=sar=40/33,trim=duration=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v4];" +
                        "[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v] -map [v] "+path+"out.mp4");


    }
```