# android app to make mp4 video from image

Tags: android, image, video, encoder

I take a picture from the camera preview and then save the obtained byte array into a jpeg file.

Now I want to save/encode that image file(jpeg) as a video file (mp4) of 2 seconds duration.

I know about MediaMuxer in Android 4.3 and I tried with the examples from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeDecodeTest.java,

but with no success i.e I get a blank video mp4 file.

I transformed an image to mp4 video with ffmpeg library for android but it takes too long and I want to avoid third-party libraries, if possible.
Please help me with a solution for my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android make animated video from list of images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images)

Comment: Hi U.Swap, Your link doesn't help me. I want to encode the image as mp4 file, and not to play an animation. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I was not very clear. What I want to do is to convert a picture taken with android camera previewcallback to h264 video basic stream. I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a repository [**here**](https://github.com/sixo/vid-proc), see this code I've made:

**TextureRenderer.kt**

```
class TextureRenderer {
    private val vertexShaderCode =
            "precision highp float;\n" +
                    "attribute vec3 vertexPosition;\n" +
                    "attribute vec2 uvs;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 varUvs;\n" +
                    "uniform mat4 mvp;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "void main()\n" +
                    "{\n" +
                    "\tvarUvs = uvs;\n" +
                    "\tgl_Position = mvp * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);\n" +
                    "}"

    private val fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "varying vec2 varUvs;\n" +
                    "uniform sampler2D texSampler;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "void main()\n" +
                    "{\t\n" +
                    "\tgl_FragColor = texture2D(texSampler, varUvs);\n" +
                    "}"


    private var vertices = floatArrayOf(
            // x, y, z, u, v
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 1f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1f, 1f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1f, 0f
    )

    private var indices = intArrayOf(
            2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2
    )

    private var program: Int
    private var vertexHandle: Int = 0
    private var bufferHandles = IntArray(2)
    private var uvsHandle: Int = 0
    private var mvpHandle: Int = 0
    private var samplerHandle: Int = 0
    private val textureHandle = IntArray(1)

    private var vertexBuffer: FloatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.size * 4).run {
        order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        asFloatBuffer().apply {
            put(vertices)
            position(0)
        }
    }

    private var indexBuffer: IntBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.size * 4).run {
        order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        asIntBuffer().apply {
            put(indices)
            position(0)
        }
    }

    init {
        // Create program
        val vertexShader: Int = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode)
        val fragmentShader: Int = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode)
        program = GLES20.glCreateProgram().also {
            GLES20.glAttachShader(it, vertexShader)
            GLES20.glAttachShader(it, fragmentShader)
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(it)
            vertexHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(it, "vertexPosition")
            uvsHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(it, "uvs")
            mvpHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(it, "mvp")
            samplerHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(it, "texSampler")
        }
        // Initialize buffers
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, bufferHandles, 0)
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[0])
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size * 4, vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[1])
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size * 4, indexBuffer, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)
        // Init texture handle
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0)
        // Ensure I can draw transparent stuff that overlaps properly
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND)
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
    }

    private fun loadShader(type: Int, shaderCode: String): Int {
        return GLES20.glCreateShader(type).also { shader ->
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode)
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader)
        }
    }

    fun draw(viewportWidth: Int, viewportHeight: Int, bitmap: Bitmap, mvpMatrix: FloatArray) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        GLES20.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, viewportWidth, viewportHeight)
        GLES20.glUseProgram(program)
        // Pass transformations to shader
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0)
        // Prepare texture for drawing
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0)
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0])
        GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0)
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST)
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST)
        // Prepare buffers with vertices and indices & draw
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[0])
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[1])
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle)
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 5, 0)
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvsHandle)
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(uvsHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 5, 3 * 4)
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
    }
}
```

**TimeLapseEncoder.kt**

```
class TimeLapseEncoder {
    private var renderer: TextureRenderer? = null

    // MediaCodec and encoding configuration
    private var encoder: MediaCodec? = null
    private var muxer: MediaMuxer? = null
    private var mime = "video/avc"
    private var trackIndex = -1
    private var presentationTimeUs = 0L
    private var frameRate = 30.0
    private val timeoutUs = 10000L
    private val bufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
    private var size: Size? = null

    // EGL
    private var eglDisplay: EGLDisplay? = null
    private var eglContext: EGLContext? = null
    private var eglSurface: EGLSurface? = null

    // Surface provided by MediaCodec and used to get data produced by OpenGL
    private var surface: Surface? = null

    fun prepareForEncoding(outVideoFilePath: String, bitmapWidth: Int, bitmapHeight: Int): Boolean {
        try {
            encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mime)
            // Try to find supported size by checking the resolution of first supplied image
            // This could also be set manually as parameter to TimeLapseEncoder
            size = getBestSupportedResolution(encoder!!, mime, Size(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight))
            val format = getFormat(size!!)
            encoder!!.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)
            // Prepare surface
            initEgl()
            // Switch to executing state - we're ready to encode
            encoder!!.start()
            // Prepare muxer
            muxer = MediaMuxer(outVideoFilePath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
            renderer = TextureRenderer()
            return true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            releaseEncoder()
            return false
        }
    }

    fun encodeFrame(bitmap: Bitmap, delay: Int): Boolean {
        return try {
            frameRate = 1000.0 / delay
            drainEncoder(false)
            renderer!!.draw(size!!.width, size!!.height, bitmap, getMvp())
            EGLExt.eglPresentationTimeANDROID(eglDisplay, eglSurface, presentationTimeUs * 1000)
            EGL14.eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface)
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            releaseEncoder()
            false
        }
    }

    fun finishEncoding(): Boolean {
        return try {
            drainEncoder(true)
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false
        } finally {
            releaseEncoder()
        }
    }

    private fun getBestSupportedResolution(mediaCodec: MediaCodec, mime: String, preferredResolution: Size): Size? {
        // First check if exact combination supported
        if (mediaCodec.codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(mime)
                        .videoCapabilities.isSizeSupported(preferredResolution.width, preferredResolution.height))
            return preferredResolution
        // I prefer similar resolution with similar aspect
        val pix = preferredResolution.width * preferredResolution.height
        val preferredAspect = preferredResolution.width.toFloat() / preferredResolution.height.toFloat()
        // I try the resolutions suggested by docs for H.264 and VP8
        // https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#video-encoding
        // TODO: find more supported resolutions
        val resolutions = arrayListOf(
                Size(176, 144), Size(320, 240), Size(320, 180),
                Size(640, 360), Size(720, 480), Size(1280, 720),
                Size(1920, 1080)
        )
        resolutions.sortWith(compareBy({ pix - it.width * it.height },
                // First compare by aspect
                {
                    val aspect = if (it.width < it.height) it.width.toFloat() / it.height.toFloat()
                    else it.height.toFloat() / it.width.toFloat()
                    (preferredAspect - aspect).absoluteValue
                }))
        for (size in resolutions) {
            if (mediaCodec.codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(mime)
                            .videoCapabilities.isSizeSupported(size.width, size.height)
            )
                return size
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun getFormat(size: Size): MediaFormat {
        val format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(mime, size.width, size.height)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 2000000)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 60)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 15)

        return format
    }

    private fun initEgl() {
        surface = encoder!!.createInputSurface()
        eglDisplay = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
        if (eglDisplay == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY)
            throw RuntimeException("eglDisplay == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY: " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(EGL14.eglGetError()))
        val version = IntArray(2)
        if (!EGL14.eglInitialize(eglDisplay, version, 0, version, 1))
            throw RuntimeException("eglInitialize(): " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(EGL14.eglGetError()))
        val attribList = intArrayOf(
                EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                EGLExt.EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID, 1,
                EGL14.EGL_NONE
        )
        val configs = arrayOfNulls<EGLConfig>(1)
        val nConfigs = IntArray(1)
        EGL14.eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, attribList, 0, configs, 0, configs.size, nConfigs, 0)
        var err = EGL14.eglGetError()
        if (err != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS)
            throw RuntimeException(GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(err))
        val ctxAttribs = intArrayOf(EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL14.EGL_NONE)
        eglContext = EGL14.eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, configs[0], EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, ctxAttribs, 0)
        err = EGL14.eglGetError()
        if (err != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS)
            throw RuntimeException(GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(err))
        val surfaceAttribs = intArrayOf(EGL14.EGL_NONE)
        eglSurface = EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, configs[0], surface, surfaceAttribs, 0)
        err = EGL14.eglGetError()
        if (err != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS)
            throw RuntimeException(GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(err))
        if (!EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext))
            throw RuntimeException("eglMakeCurrent(): " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(EGL14.eglGetError()))
    }

    private fun drainEncoder(endOfStream: Boolean) {
        if (endOfStream)
            encoder!!.signalEndOfInputStream()
        while (true) {
            val outBufferId = encoder!!.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, timeoutUs)
            if (outBufferId >= 0) {
                val encodedBuffer = encoder!!.getOutputBuffer(outBufferId)!!
                // MediaMuxer is ignoring KEY_FRAMERATE, so I set it manually here
                // to achieve the desired frame rate
                bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = presentationTimeUs
                muxer!!.writeSampleData(trackIndex, encodedBuffer, bufferInfo)
                presentationTimeUs += (1000000.0 / frameRate).toLong()
                encoder!!.releaseOutputBuffer(outBufferId, false)
                // Are we finished here?
                if ((bufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0)
                    break
            } else if (outBufferId == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                if (!endOfStream)
                    break
                // End of stream, but still no output available. Try again.
            } else if (outBufferId == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                trackIndex = muxer!!.addTrack(encoder!!.outputFormat)
                muxer!!.start()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getMvp(): FloatArray {
        val mvp = FloatArray(16)
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mvp, 0)
        Matrix.scaleM(mvp, 0, 1f, -1f, 1f)
        return mvp
    }

    private fun releaseEncoder() {
        encoder?.stop()
        encoder?.release()
        encoder = null
        releaseEgl()
        muxer?.stop()
        muxer?.release()
        muxer = null
        size = null
        trackIndex = -1
        presentationTimeUs = 0L
    }

    private fun releaseEgl() {
        if (eglDisplay != EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
            EGL14.eglDestroySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurface)
            EGL14.eglDestroyContext(eglDisplay, eglContext)
            EGL14.eglReleaseThread()
            EGL14.eglTerminate(eglDisplay)
        }
        surface?.release()
        surface = null
        eglDisplay = EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY
        eglContext = EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT
        eglSurface = EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
val outputPath = ...
val videoFile = File(outputPath)
if (videoFile.exists())
    videoFile.delete()
videoFile.parentFile!!.mkdirs()
val timeLapseEncoder = TimeLapseEncoder()
val width=...
val height=...
timeLapseEncoder.prepareForEncoding(outputPath, width, height))
val bitmap=...
val delay=... //in ms, of this specific frame
timeLapseEncoder.encodeFrame(bitmap, delay)
timeLapseEncoder.finishEncoding()
```