# Efficient and fast way to encode images to Video/GIF in Android

Tags: java, android, video, gpu, encode

I'm trying to make a video out of viewshots in an app.
I have succeeeded to get the images as Bitmaps using this code.

```
    public Bitmap getScreenShot() {
    View screenView = findViewById(R.id.button);
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return bitmap;
    }
```

I have encode images using SequenceEncoder like this :

```
for(Bitmap bitmap : bitmaps)
    sequenceEncoder.encodeImage(bitmap);
```

I have got it working and got the file but it takes a lot of time.
I have also tried to use MediaMuxer(I used [EncodeDecode](http://m.blog.csdn.net/wang___t/article/details/45717123)) but failed to even get a video, I have tried to make a GIF(using [AnimatedGifEncoder](https://gist.github.com/wasabeef/8785346)) but a lot of time too. I want a way to make this video in a very short time.

Comment: Maybe these will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839777/878126 https://github.com/sixo/vid-proc